# HTML5 Video Autoplay not working correctly

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video, autoplay

I'm using this code:

```
<video width="440px" loop="true" autoplay="true" controls>
<source src="http://www.example.com/CorporateVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="http://www.example.com/CorporateVideo.ogv" type="video/ogv" />
<source src="http://www.example.com/CorporateVideo.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

I want the video to autoplay but when the page loads the video doesn't play. It looks like it's a buffering issue, as when I hover on the video (to show controls) the video is always 2 seconds in but then stops and doesn't continue.

Note: I just visited the site again and autoplay seemed to work, but when I try again the same issue is happening, is this a buffering issue? Anything I can do to stop this?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try `autoplay="autoplay"` instead of the `"true"` value. That's the documented way to enable autoplay. That sounds weirdly redundant, I know.

Comment: use this snippet its cross browser compatile - I have tested this its working perfecly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848236/html-video-autoplay-not-working-in-firefox/45869587#45869587a

Answer (score 68):

Chrome does not allow autoplay if the video is not muted. Try using this:

```
<video width="440px" loop="true" autoplay="autoplay" controls muted>
  <source src="http://www.tuscorlloyds.com/CorporateVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="http://www.tuscorlloyds.com/CorporateVideo.ogv" type="video/ogv" />
  <source src="http://www.tuscorlloyds.com/CorporateVideo.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

Comment: nice, its work for me

Answer (score 31):

Mobile browsers generally ignore this attribute to prevent consuming data until user explicitly starts the download.

**UPDATE**: newer version of mobile browser on Android and iOS do support autoplay function. But **it only works if the video is muted or has no audio channel**:

Some additional info:
https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Comment: So how can one force autoplay for mobiles ?

Comment: Just use it like a simple attribute: <video controls autoplay>

Comment: And we must use the muted attribute , correct ? - it is working very sporadically ( for my tests at least ) depending on phone model / browser

Comment: Yes, that's right, if the video has audio channel then muted attribute is necessary: <video controls autoplay muted >

Comment: my findings are 'muted' works even with audio channels:
http://curious-electric.com/pens/video/

Answer (score 8):

Working solution **October 2018**, for videos including audio channel

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('video').prop('muted',true).play()
 });
```

Have a look at another of mine, more in-depth answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57723549/3049675

Comment: `$('video').attr('data-keepplaying', '')` is unnecessary. The `muted` property is the important part.

Answer (score 1):

```css
html {
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

body {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

video {
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<video onloadeddata="this.play();this.muted=false;" poster="https://durian.blender.org/wp-content/themes/durian/images/void.png" playsinline loop muted controls>
    <source src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag or the file format of this video.
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use it:
autoplay controls muted

Answer (score -2):

You might want to add some scripts if your software doesn't support jQuery or giving any reference type error.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
//Use above scripts only if the software you are working on doesn't support jQuery.

<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {

//Change the location of your mp3 or any music file. 
        var source = "../Assets/music.mp3";
    
        var audio = new Audio();
        audio.src = source;
        audio.autoplay = true;
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your answer to add some explanation and details. While it might answer the question, just adding some code does not help OP or future community members understand the issue or solution.