# HTML Video autoplay not working in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, video

I have a website built with bootstrap and loading video in a dialog:

```
<video width="760" style="background-color: white;" preload controls autoplay>
    <source src="....." type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Shows and works fine in IE, Chrome and Safari.
In Firefox auto play worked a few times, and now does not work at all.
No errors in console and video plays just fine manually using controls.

I have also tried script approach (without autoplay attribute):

```
oncanplay="$(this)[0].play()"
```

And works flawlessly on all browsers except Firefox.

Can anyone see what could be wrong?

Comment: can you share the link?

Comment: you could just do `oncanplay="this.play()"` just heads up no need to wrap and unwrap jQuery :-)

Answer (score 23):

**I have tested this on all browser its working perfect with javascript event**

```
<video onloadeddata="this.play();" poster="poster.png" playsinline loop muted controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="video.mp4.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="video.mp4.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag or the file format of this video.
</video>
```

Comment: Important to notice that it won't work with firefox browser if the user had blocked the autoplay function, and it's blocked by default.

Answer (score 4):

The problem has an easy solution: **changing the order of the videos**, listing first the `.mp4` source and next the `.webm` source made the auto-play videos run on Firefox, Explorer and Chrome, this of course is valid if you have multiple video sources.

A side note: Firefox supports `H.264` on Windows 7 and later since version 21. Firefox supports `H.264` on Linux since version 26 if the appropriate `gstreamer` plug-ins are installed. Partial support for Firefox refers to the lack of support in OSX & some Linux platforms, for Android Firefox it refers to the inability of hardware acceleration.

Comment: Also tried something like that... I have put the webm alone as source... same problem... Put the ogv alone... same problem... I will try the exactly the order you have said and try...

Comment: Also, the first time when video is opened, it plays flawlessly... second time OK, third time OK, and so on... Once I use the Stop or Pause button in controls, any subsequent auto play is not working... Refreshing the page does not work

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me for the firefox browser, but it have to be muted.

```html
<video
   width="100%"
   height="100%"
   onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true"
   autoplay
>
   <source src="assets/videos/Helpline_Video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

**First check your web page here for test**

```
http://html5test.com/
```

**Second** inspect via code inspector and enter them in the browser to check if the are working fine or not. Or drag and drop video file over the browser to check if its working or not.

**Thirdly try checking MIME Types**

```
AddType video/mp4 for .mp4 .m4v
AddType video/ogg for .ogv
AddType video/webm for .webm
```

**Fourthly** check you html5 converter it has often problem with format conversion I had same problem year back when I was working html5 video. Changing it fixed the issue for me.

**Last** but not the least; Add a flash fall-back!

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
data="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf"
height="227" width="220">
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox Video Issue: Troubleshooting

1. Make sure that the server sends the video files with a correct and supported MIME type to make it work in Firefox.

   [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements)
2. Use source URL relative to ROOT, not Web page

   Eg: src="/complete/folder/path/video.ogv"
3. Version of mozilla.

   - Mozilla Firefox (3.5 and later) supports Theora video and Vorbis audio in an Ogg container.
   - Firefox 4 supports WebM.

   [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats)

Answer (score 0):

From Firefox 66 and aboew, you must click the unblock button on the right of browser bar to unblock Autoplay Video and Audio