# Video do not autoplay on mobile devices

Tags: html

I use this tag and attributes for autoplay my background video -

```
<video src="fire.mp4" autoplay loop muted playsinline ></video>
```

But if i want to check my website from my iPhone and my battery mode is economy - video do not autoplay. Maybe i lost some attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting an attribute for autoplay and the other values, like this?

```
<video src="fire.mp4" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" playsinline="playsinline"></video>
```

You could try a bit of simple JS to make it as robust as possible. See this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/45869587/13655534