# HTML5 Video not autoplaying

Tags: html, video, autoplay

MIME type is accepted, I've checked.

Here is how it is looking like: https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/5441bde46b6fcb86daf55d73/594x351/122b8cad9f5824c44fa25fb242569312/upload_5_14_2015_at_5_10_18_PM.png

Here is the website in question (go to animation in menu): www.ivocunha.com

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" controls autoplay loop class="bl-box fancybox-effects-d" title="Walk">
                          <source src="img/animation/walk.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                          Your browser does not support the video tag.
                        </video>
```

Why doesn't it autoplay?

Comment: Just to be clear, it does play when the user clicks the play button?

Comment: hmmm - that code works for me using the absolute path http://www.ivocunha.com/img/animation/walk.mp4

Comment: What browsers have you tested in? Does autoplay work in any of them?

Comment: I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16965170/1016716), that says "Mobile browsers generally ignore this attribute (...)"

Comment: This behaviour is true for all mainstream browsers: chrome, ie, firefox (stable channels). The testing is being done all in the full version, not the mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you are using section tags to wrap your video in you should not use sections for content that does not have a heading. It is not a wrapper.

as for your video remove auto play because they are auto playing by the looks of it but using auto play within your video tag triggers auto play from page entry and they are all playing at the same time.

you then want to use your jquery and create an on hover that will play your video and pause it on exit. your code doesnt seem to be doing that at all on your site instead its only trigering for points.

I would give this a read over so you can see how to use the api properly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Comment: Hi, thanks for you kind answer.

1) I tried removing the section tags, doesn't help the formatting I want. I need them.

2) Removing autoplay also doesn't make it autoplay. Even if they play all at once, doesn't annoy at all, because they all have an image over them, that disapears when you mouse over it (allowing then to see the video).

3) I will check this jquery thing and reply back here when I can. But so far, nothing has solutioned this with html5, which is what I wanted...

Thanks for link, I'm checking it now.

Comment: 1.Sorry you don't seem to understand that you shouldn't be using section tags for formatting your code is wrong if you don't have a title tag inside a section then its incorrect. 2. It doesn't matter if it annoys your or not your page is running at no speed at all because you have a load of videos trying to run in the browser all at once. and will massively impact the user. you have the site cached in your browser your probably not even noticing it anymore.