# html5 autoplay video in Mobile device

Tags: html

Auto play is not working without **muted** attribute, when I try to open url in mobile device. How to play video without using **muted** attribute ? I need to volume without click on muted button and one more important thing is that all thing will be working without **JS and Jquery**.   [image]

Comment: check this one also for autoplay video:
Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965170/html5-video-autoplay-not-working-correctly

Comment: I check your given link but it is work only desktop and when I opened in mobile device then video is replace by image. I also try your code but this is not working

Answer (score 36):

You wont be able to achieve this in iOS without hacks. From the official Apple WebKit documentation:

> Starting in iOS 10, WebKit relaxes its inline and autoplay policies to
>   make these presentations possible, but still keeps in mind sites’
>   bandwidth and users’ batteries.
>
> By default, WebKit will have the following policies:
>
> - video elements will be allowed to autoplay without a user gesture if their source media contains no audio tracks.
> - **video muted** elements will also be allowed to autoplay without a user gesture. If a  element gains an audio track or becomes un-muted without a user gesture, playback will pause.

https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

As for Mobile Chrome (Android):

> Muted autoplay for video is supported by Chrome for Android as of
>   version 53. Playback will start automatically for a video element once
>   it comes into view if both autoplay and **muted are set**, and playback of
>   muted videos can be initiated progamatically with play(). Previously,
>   playback on mobile had to be initiated by a user gesture, regardless
>   of the muted state.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay

Comment: On iPhone, `autoplay muted` worked for me only after adding `playsinline` attribute

Comment: Just to confirm, even though I used `muted` the autoplay wasn't working on iPhone Chrome. Adding `playsinline` fixed the issue. BTW the video still plays fullscreen - this attr apparently doesn't override `object-fit: cover;`.

Answer (score 20):

On Ios make sure you don't have energy-saving on. This makes it so the video won't play.

Comment: I just spent hours figuring out why my video isn't autoplaying... it was cause energy-saving mode turned on.

Comment: I spent hours and when I turned off the power saving mode of iPhone 12, it started playing again. As being a developer I checked my code multiple times but no success. It was mobile energy saving causing issue.

Answer (score 19):

```
<video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted defaultMuted playsinline  oncontextmenu="return false;"  preload="auto"  id="myVideo">
        <source src="assets/video/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
```

This code worked for me on Ios and Android phone

Answer (score 5):

Simply include `defaultMuted` inline with your video to enable sound on autoplay. For example,

```
 <video id="myVideo" defaultMuted autoplay controls>
     <source src="myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_defaultmuted.asp

Comment: Thanks! the "muted" attribute alone wasn't working for me but "defaultMuted" did :)

Comment: defaultMuted is not an HTML attribute, but javascript property. In html, you use muted attribute. So this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Lovor you're right, but it works so leave it be

Answer (score 1):

I can't really make any sense of it but this managed to work on iOS Safari and Firefox (haven't tested Android):

```
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop id="DemoReel2018">
<source src="resources/AgsVision_backgroundMovie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

...thing is, it only work after I set the viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

If anyone can actually explain why that happened, I'd really want to know. Otherwise...stay tuned for more wacky stuff :))

Answer (score 0):

You Try this one link also they have provide more Information about Why The Change?:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay

Answer (score 0):

Its simple see the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Example movie autoplay</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">                
</head>
<body>
    <video autoplay muted>
        <source src="midia/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="midia/video.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

You need check the browsers and the formats supported.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#Browser_compatibility

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work for you

```
<video  autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted defaultMuted playsinline>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is an angular project don't forget to write [muted]="'muted'". Normal muted attribute is not working.

So, 'Autoplay' is working well on mobile browsers as well in this code-snippet below:

```
<video [muted]="'muted'" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" playsinline id="video-start">
    <!-- My Dynamic Content -->
    <source *ngIf="backgroundVideo?.Link?.Url" [src]="backgroundVideo.Link.Url" type="video/mp4">

    <!-- My Default Content, displaying when dynamic content has a problem -->
    <source [src]="baseURL + '/assets/videos/film_home.mp4'" type="video/mp4">

    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```