# Dynamically added videos using jquery not playing on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js, video-player

I am trying to display video preview when some one touch on that screen on `touchstart` event by dynamically add video tag and video source (which is `.webm`) video and will start to play automatically. I can fetch the video tag but video is not getting played. 
Here is my code:

```
<div class="thumb-overlay playthumb">
    <img src="http://img.domain.com/thumbs/2.jpg" title="" alt="" id="2" class="img-responsive ">
    <div class="duration">15:11</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".playthumb").on('touchstart', function(event) {
        var thumb = $(this).children('img')[0];
        var id = thumb.id;
        $('#thumbPlayerM').remove();
        var video = $('<video style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;padding:0;margin:0;" id="thumbPlayerM" class="img-fluid" loop=""></video>');
        var content = '<source type="video/webm" src="http://img.domain.com/webm/' + id + '/' + id + '.webm"></source>';
        $(video).append(content);
        $(video).hide();
        var target = $("#" + id);
        $(target).after($(video));
        $(video)[0].play();
        $(video).fadeIn();
    });
});
</script>
```

I even try this also

```
var vid = $("#thumbPlayerM");
vid.play();
$(video).fadeIn();
```

Video is coming over the image but not playing. Any one can help me? Thank you.

Comment: Is the line `var id = thumb.id;` returning the `id` properly?

Comment: There are limitations about video play and specially autoplay on mobiles, for data consuption reasons, [more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160528/html5-autoplay-video-in-mobile-device#42161532)

Comment: Hello @chade_ Yes, id returns properly. Btw, i got it fixed

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue, need to add this:

```
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline></video>
```

My videos are already muted but I have no idea why it was not working. I must check my encoder.