# Why isn't the video autoplaying on mobile devices?

Tags: html, video, mobile

I was just wondering, why does the `<video>` element not auto-play on mobile devices, such as Android and IOS. Do these platforms and support videos?

```
<div class="video-test-animated col span-2-of-2">
   <video class="video-size"  autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="videos/final-video-background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>      
</div>
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160528/html5-autoplay-video-in-mobile-device

Comment: but no one explains the answer there.