# Play video whith delay on mobile browser with jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to start a video with a 5 second delay after loading the page.

On desktop browser i solved in this way:

```
setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('video').trigger('play'); }, 5000);
```

The problem is that the code dosen't work on mobile browser.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Autoplay only seems to be allowed when the video has no audio or has the `muted` attribute: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160528/html5-autoplay-video-in-mobile-device

Comment: Does this answer your question? [html5 autoplay video in Mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160528/html5-autoplay-video-in-mobile-device)

Comment: The video have the 'muted' attribute

Comment: The following docs may help: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay-2/