# How to play iframe video using JavaScript (not youtube)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iframe

How can I play an video element inside an iframe.  The iframe is automatically creating the video element and controls. There are many answers here pointing to add `&autoplay` to the `src` address but this is not a youtube iframe.

My HTML code:

```
<button @click="playVideo(item.name)">play</button>
<iframe :ref="item.name" autoplay :src="item.video_link" :title='item.name'></iframe>
```

JS

```
playVideo(itemName) {
     
      this.$refs[itemName] <--- this give me the iframe DOM element I want to play

    },
```

Rendered HTML:

[image]

Comment: I think it depends on how the source works

Comment: would you mind to try <video> tag?  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

Comment: the source is a mp4 file (hosted on ipfs)

Comment: if the iframe is not same origin as your page, you can't touch it

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the source MP4, you should be using [`<video>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) instead of an iframe. You'll then have full access to [`autoplay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-autoplay), [`controls`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-controls) and other features.

Based on your code, this would look something like:

```html
<video :ref="item.name" autoplay :title='item.name'>
  <source :src="item.video_link" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

---

And since IPFS can be a bit slow for first load, you can also specify [`poster`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-poster) to show a thumbnail while the content is loading. Here's an example using an IPFS source:

```html
<h3>IPFS Embeded Video Demo</h3>  
          <!--  required for autoplay in Chrome --> 
<video autoplay muted autopictureinpicture controls poster="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9qG3.jpg?s=256&g=1" height="200">
  <source src="https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmbGtJg23skhvFmu9mJiePVByhfzu5rwo74MEkVDYAmF5T" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Comment: Apparently, Chrome currently only allows `autoplay` of `muted` videos (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607588/chrome-video-autoplay)), so I added it to make it work. You might want to specify it clearly in your answer, as I'm expecting others to stumble on this in the future. Cheers!